# add 2 rows ignoring NaN partially

Tags: matlab, vector, addition, nan, cell-array

I have 2 columns/vectors given in a cell Array. Both vectors do have always the same length. The first vector has some values in it, randomly some NaN. The second vector has NaN's until a specific Point, then only values. Now I want to add both vectors to one with the same length. It can occur, that the calculation is NaN + NaN, then the result should be NaN as well. If I have a value + NaN, the result should be value.

How is this possible to do?

Is it easier to solve, if I added the vectors, having empty cells instead of NaN? But I can't add two cell vectors, as well as I can't use cell2mat when there are empty cells.

For example

```
a = {NaN;2;3;NaN;5};
b = {1;2;NaN;NaN;5};
```

should result in

```
c = a+b = {1;4;3;NaN;10};
```

Comment: Based on your explanation, should the result be {1,4,3,NaN,10}? And by 'empty cells', do you mean cells with a NaN in them?

Comment: of course!, thank you, i edited it

Comment: can you give an example of what your {a} looks like exactly in matlab? is it something like {' ';'2';'3';' ';'5'} ?

Comment: in its origin, there is a large cell Array. the first column includes Dates, all others values. But not every cell is filled with data, some are empty. In order to handle this Array, i filled every empty cell with NaN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly:

You should be able to convert your cell arrays to vectors. The NaNs will not become empty values, but will become NaN flags. You can then start by adding together your vectors, and then update the final vector using some logical indexing and the built-in IsNaN function.

```
a = cell2mat(a);
b = cell2mat(b);

c = a + b;

c(isnan(a) & ~isnan(b)) = b(isnan(a) & ~isnan(b));
c(~isnan(a) & isnan(b)) = a(~isnan(a) & isnan(b));
```

Comment: perfect! thank you very much. didn't think about logical indexing. truely genius from you :)